# Ruby object in my JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have a Ruby object and I want to use that object in JavaScript. I haven't seen that type of thing, but I want a Ruby object in my .js file.

Is this possible?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't use your Ruby objects in JavaScript. You can, however, request any data encoded with JSON or XML (even plain text or your own data format) from the server-side using AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

You can only pass strings, json or xml. Though, you can do it without ajax.

```
# dynamic_data.js.erb

var js_data = <%= Time.now.to_s -%> 

# show.html.erb

render :partial => 'dynamic_data'
```

or

```
- content_for :head do
    = javascript_tag "var js_data = #{ Time.now.to_s };"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Ruby objects within JavaScript because **Ruby code executes on the server and JavaScript executes within the client Web browser**. However, you can execute Ruby code and then use the results within JavaScript as [Mark illustrates in his answer to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387667/ruby-object-in-my-javascript-file/3387837#3387837).